# O nome 'Component' não existe no contexto atual

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Eu estou tentando criar um view component para reutilizar nas páginas, estou tentando seguir alguns tutoriais em video. Já instalei via nuget o Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc inteiro, mas quando eu tento chamá-lo a partir da viewpage, usando

```
@Component.InvokeAsync("Componente")
```

eu tenho o erro

O nome 'Component' não existe no contexto atual

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando VS2017, asp.net mvc 5.
Alguem sabe oque pode estar faltando? Instalar alguma outra coisa que não sei?
Ou no mvc 5 é de outra forma a chamada do component?

Quando eu começo a digitar Compon e pressiono ctrl+espaço deveria aparecer a lista de opções incluindo o Component conforme a imagem a seguir, nota-se que Component não está aparecendo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual a versão do asp.net? Se não me engano oViewComponent está disponível partindo do mvc core 1.1

Comment: dotnet --version
2.1.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu caso o problema é porque *View Components* é um recurso apresentado no **MVC 6** e **Asp.Net 5** e a sua aplicação é na verdade um **MVC5** com **Asp.Net 4**

Abaixo segue um exemplo da implementação no DoteNetCore ([referência](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1)).

Primeiro crie um diretório, na raiz da sua aplicação MVC, chamado *ComponentsView* e adicione uma nova classe chamada `ComponenteViewComponent`
que deve herdar da `ViewComponent`

```
public class ComponenteViewComponent : ViewComponent
{

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Se você não respeitar o sufixo *ViewComponent* o MVC não a reconhecerá como tal e talvez aí possa estar o seu primeiro problema. Se você criou a classe chamando apenas de `Componente`, você precisa adicionar uma anotação para que o componente seja reconhecido por esse nome.

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "Componente")]
public class Componente : ViewComponent
{

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Observado os pontos acima e após a criação da classe, vá até o diretório */Views/Shared/*, adicione o diretório *Components* e dentro dela mais uma pasta chamada *Componente*, que é o nome do seu componente.

Dentro da pasta *Componente* adicione a `PartialView` chamada `Default`, meu exemplo eu adicionei apenas o seguinte trecho de html:

```
<h1>Olá eu sou um componente</h1>
```

Por fim sua estrutura deverá estar assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora, em uma view qualquer do seu site você pode invocar o seu componente, no meu caso adicionei o trecho no topo da view Index da HomeController:

```
<div>
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Componente")
</div>
```

E o Resultado é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito interessante!

Comment: Ele acaba funcionando como um "MVC dentro do MVC", permite o reuso de muitos componentes com uma maleabilidade e desacoplamento maior do que com simples partials views

Comment: @LeandroAngelo refiz exatamente seguindo os passos citados, mas o continuo com problema, o problema ainda esta na chamada do componente na view. agora com o await aparece o mesmo erro da imagem que foi anexada na pergunta, agora sendo: O nome 'await' não existe no contexto atual. será q eu não tenho q instalar algo pelo nuget que eu não estou sabendo? eu instalei esse: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc

Comment: Como está a sua _ViewImports.cshtml na raiz da pasta views

Comment: Na raiz da pasta Views arquivos tem só _ViewStart.cshtml e Web.config, no _ViewStart.cshtml tem o seguinte conteúdo:@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

Comment: Quando eu começo a digitar Compon e pressiono ctrl+espaço deveria aparecer a lista de opções incluindo o Component conforme a imagem  anexada na pergunta agora pouco nota-se que Component não está aparecendo.

Comment: Web.Config??? você criou o projeto como?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78547/discussion-between-jonas-centenaro-and-leandro-angelo).