# Como chamar método na controller por uma View

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Nessa Dropdown

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Grupo de Desconto", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Grupo de Descontos", new SelectList(ViewBag.Desconto, "Id", "Descricao"))
            @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HomeTemplateId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
        </div>
    </div>
```

Como eu faço para quando selecionar um item, ela chamar um método na controller para filtrar uma table(grid) passando o ID na Dropdown?

**EDIT1**

Bem, refiz e consigo com a jquery chegar a controller. Alterop a ViewBag que popula o Grid(Table), mas o grid não recarrega. Essa é a nova Action

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Details(AzureDiscountGroupModel modelD, int id)
        {            
            var discount = _azureDiscountGroupService.GetAll();
            var list = new List<ResellerListModel>();

            var resellers = _resellerService.QueryAll()
                .Include(r => r.WhiteLabels)
                .ToList();

            foreach(var item in resellers)
            {
                list.Add(CreateListModelFrom(item));
            }
            ViewBag.Desconto = discount.Where(x => x.Id > 0);
            ViewBag.DetailReseller = list.Where(x => x.AzureDiscountGroupId == id).ToList();
            return View(modelD);
        }
```

Mudei a jquery para essa

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#GrupoDescontos").change(function () {
     $.ajax
         ({
            url: '' + $(this).val(),
            type: 'GET',
             success: function (dados) {
             $("#GridDetail").html(dados);
             var resultado = dados;
        },
        error: function (erro) {

        }
     });
  });
});
```

Tudo parece estar ok, mas o grid não atualiza. Essa a cshtml do projeto

```
@model Atma.SND.CSP.WhiteLabel.Site.Areas.API.Models.AzureDiscountGroups.AzureDiscountGroupModel
@using Atma.SND.CSP.SubscriptionCenter.API.Models.Resellers

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<style>
    .Makewide { width: 200px; }
</style>

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>AzureDiscountGroupModel</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Grupo de Desconto", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("GrupoDescontos", new SelectList(ViewBag.Desconto, "Id", "Descricao"), new { @id = "GrupoDescontos", @class= "Makewide" })
            @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HomeTemplateId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Nome
        </th>
        <th>
            Alias
        </th>
        <th>
            WhiteLabel?
        </th>
        <th>
            MPN Id
        </th>
        <th>
            Criada em
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.DetailReseller as List<ResellerListModel>)
    {
    <tr align="center">
        <td>
            @(item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @(item.Alias)
        </td>
        <td>
            @(item.WhiteLabel ? "Sim" : "Não")
        </td>
        <td>
            @(item.MpnId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @(item.CreatedOn)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }

</table>

<p>   
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#GrupoDescontos").change(function () {
        $.ajax
            ({
                url: '' + $(this).val(),
            type: 'GET', 
                success: function (dados) {

                    alert(1);
                var resultado = dados;
            },
            error: function (erro) {

            }
});
  });
});
</script>
```

A PartialView que criei

```
<div id="GridDetail">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Nome
            </th>
            <th>
                Alias
            </th>
            <th>
                WhiteLabel?
            </th>
            <th>
                MPN Id
            </th>
            <th>
                Criada em
            </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.DetailReseller as List<ResellerListModel>)
        {
            <tr align="center">
                <td>
                    @(item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @(item.Alias)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @(item.WhiteLabel ? "Sim" : "Não")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @(item.MpnId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @(item.CreatedOn)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Quando entro na details ela já filtra a table, só queria saber como eu faço da View para refazer, ou seja, seleciono outro Grupo e pelo ID desse grupo, já filtro

Comment: Essa é uma alternativa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/304892/o-nome-component-n%C3%A3o-existe-no-contexto-atual/304939#304939

Comment: Estou tentando pegar o valor da Dropdown assim: `$(this).val();` mas não funciona

Comment: Veja, consegui enviar o id correto a cada change da Dropdown, entra na controller, altera a ViewBag que carrega o grid, mas não exibe as alterações no grid. No grid nada acontece

Comment: Tem a ver com estar ou não no servidor?

Comment: Ajax... você precisa fazer uma requisição e atualizar o conteúdo da sua página

Comment: Mas como eu faço isso, @LeandroAngelo? Tentando por partial view e não consegui nada

Comment: Onde que esta o elemento com este ID aqui? #GridDetail que nao achei no seu HTML?
Deve ser por isso.. no caso a Grid a qual vc se refere é a Table?

Comment: A questão toda é como formular a pergunta, esse é o problema. Pergunta mal feita, não tem resposta e não consigo ser mais direto